# Eliminar posiciones en blanco al leer archivo excel

Tags: c#

Tengo un excel que estoy leyendo, y en la siguiente imagen en la posición `73`, efectivamente termina el documento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema que hay una posición `74` y `75` lo que causa que este re registre 2 veces mas, por lo que ocupo eliminar estos.

Necesito un método que me elimine las posiciones con espacios en blanco, algún método?

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XX\XXXX\XXXXXX\" + ruta);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] data = line.Split(',');
    if (lines.Length > 1)
    {
        if (data[0] == "XXXX:")
        {                       
            info.XXXX= data[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Busco por palabra en el excel, donde encuentra alguna, entra y lo agrega a la lista y asi sucesivamente...

Comment: Puedes añadir el código de cómo lees y recorres el excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) para comprobar que esa línea no esté vacía, y entonces tratar o no con la línea, de la siguiente forma:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XX\XXXX\XXXXXX\" + ruta);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(',');
        if (lines.Length > 1)
        {
            if (data[0] == "XXXX:")
            {                       
                info.XXXX= data[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente :o